# Scale the ARcamera in Unity for Cardboard Vuforia project makes tracking inaccurate

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, google-cardboard

I'm now working on a project with Cardboard+ Vuforia in Unity.
By default the stereoscreens are small on mobile screen.
[By Default snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3pkD.jpg)

but the image tracking is accurate, even if I moved the image to the border of the screen.
[Move to border snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/As5yV.jpg)

Limited to the resolution of the mobile phone, I had to enlarge the stereoscreens size, otherwise  the real words on image cannot be recoginzed.
Then I scaled ARcamera's transform to twice, it's ok to show contents on mobile screen and the words on image can be recognized.
[Double size snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKzjH.jpg)

But the image tracking seems not changed as twice, so if I scan the image at the middle of the camera , and move to the border of the screen , it makes large distance between image and the AR contents
[Doublesize and move to border snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fpfss.jpg)

As I used vuforia 9.8.8 in which there's no clear cardboard supporting configuration such as " screen to lens distance" as which has existed in old version of vuforia , what I can do know to fix this problem?

Comment: Could u post sample Image Tracking poses when in the middle and when close to border of the screen, ARCamera's transform before and after scaling, and the stereo screen size before and after enlarging?

Comment: @sonuthomas Could you see the above 4 snapshot?I did post the mobile phone's screenshots.
If you click the link , you can see the picture.
And by default , the scale in transform of ARcamera is 1,1,1 with small screen result.
and I change the scale into 2,2,2, got the bigger screen and inaccurate tracking

Comment: Sorry, I meant to post the Pose matrix values, the 3x4 matrix or sometimes 4x4 matrix

Comment: @sonuthomas refer to the last answer in https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues/795, I think it's the mechnazim of unity (not relate to vuforia , barely relate to cardboard). Keep searching the solution